# Regex for extracting every character except numbers and specific words at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract everything starting with `//` till numbers ending with specific texts given this string below:

```
// Peter F. Hamilton|Pandora's Star 200 OK
```

Numbers and texts are here [Response.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) and [Response.statusText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText). I have tried this regex which works for this specific string

```
\/\/.*[^200 OK]
```

But, `status` and `statusText`can be various, and I need a regex that works for all the cases. I have tried this regex with the non-capturing group but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
\/\/.*(?:\d+\s(OK|Not Found|Continue))
```

Comment: Try `\/\/(.*?)(?=\d+\s(?:OK|Not Found|Continue)|$)`

Comment: If you want to extract what is before, you can capture that part, and match what comes after `\/\/(.*?)\s*\d+(?:\s*(?:OK|Not Found|Continue))` https://regex101.com/r/92Qrqe/1

Answer (score 0):

Http status codes range from `1xx` to `5xx`.  Generally, we can try the following approach:

```js
var input = "// Peter F. Hamilton|Pandora's Star 200 OK";
var text = input.match(/(\/\/.*) [1-5][0-9]{2}( \w+)+/, input)[1];
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concerned with the middle text, you can use the following:

```
\/\/(.*)(?:(?:\d\d\d).*)$
```

This will give you the desired text in group 1 (with potentially extra spaces that you can trim).

Since http status codes are three digits, we can assume the last occurrence of three digits in the input string is where the status code starts, and everything after that is the status code description.